# ImportError No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have Python 3.6 installed with Matplotlib and I created a small program, which runs and plots the graph fine. Now, I want to export the data from this program into a MySQL database. I downloaded MySQL/Python connector, which only supports Python 3.4. So, I installed Python 3.4 as well. Now,I have two Python installed.
My program runs fine if I do

```
python test.py
```

If I go into 3.4 installation directory and run the same command, it fails with the error 'No module named matplotlib'.
If I do

```
pip install matplotlib
```

from 3.4 directory, then it says 'requirements already satisfied'.
Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

Calling pip like this, it's not about the current directory, but just about your system paths. If you want to be sure, you can always go to `python-env/Scripts/pip` (your python-binary would be at `python-env/python`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your installs separate.  The path statement is getting messed up.  I would suggest getting [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).  Once you install it you can get all the packages and dependencies in one action.

```
conda create -n py34project python=3.4 matplotlib ipython other_package
```

then easily get python 3.6

```
conda create -n py36project python=3.6 matplotlib ipython other_package
```

you can use:
`source activate py36project` to enter the environment (which will fix the path problem) and leave the environment with `source deactivate`